# read csv file with multipe matrix

Tags: r

I have a csv file which contains many matrices. For example,

```
 A  B  C
A  0  3  4
B  5  0  7
C  7  8  0

   A  B  C  D
A  0  3  4  5 
B  5  0  7  9
C  7  8  0  5
D  7  8  6  0
```

All matrices are separated by a blank line.

I want to import these two matrices into matrix file in one time.
some code like this

```
my_data <- read.csv("file.csv",head=TRUE, row.names =1 )
my_matrix <-as.matrix(my_data)
```

However, I can only import one matrix in one time. Please tell me how to import the two matrix into matrix file in one time.

Comment: Do you want the different matrix to be imported into the same matrix file, or each to be imported simultaneously into its own matrix? It isn't clear from your question.

Comment: Find whoever created the files and slap them. The rule is simple: one file, one table.

Comment: I wanna each to be imported simultaneously into its own matrix.

Answer (score 0):

This only does one physical read of the file and then extracts the two matrices from what it has read.  Using the file created in the Note at the end, read it into `L` using `readLines` and then locate the index of the separating line `ix`.  Then read the character vector `L` twice.

```
L <- trimws(readLines("myfile.dat"))
ix <- which(nchar(L) == 0)[1]
m1 <- read.table(text = L, nrows = ix-2)
m2 <- read.table(text = L, skip = ix)
```

This reads the file multiple times but the code is slightly shorter.

```
ix >- which(count.fields("myfile.dat") == 0)[1]
m1 <- read.table("myfile.dat", nrows = ix-2)
m2 <- read.table("myfile.dat", skip = ix)
```

### Note

Input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "A  B  C
A  0  3  4
B  5  0  7
C  7  8  0

   A  B  C  D
A  0  3  4  5 
B  5  0  7  9
C  7  8  0  5
D  7  8  6  0"
cat(Lines, file = "myfile.dat")
```